# Why prevent a file from opening as controlling terminal (with O_NOCTTY)?

Tags: c, linux

The purpose of O_NOCTTY is documented as :

> O_NOCTTY - prevent the OS from assigning the opened file as the
>   process's controlling terminal when opening a TTY device file

Can somebody explain the intention of preventing a file as opening a controlling terminal ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Having a controlling tty means there are certain conditions where specific signals might be sent to your program in response to things happening on the tty/window where your program is running. If the program is intended to be a daemon, it's generally cleaner to make sure you don't have a controlling tty than it is to try to write code to handle all the extra conditions that you don't really care about to begin with...

Comment: can you give an example of such case which controlling terminal will have to take care ?

Comment: @JVN Just looking at possible signals - SIGINT (usually mapped to ctrl-c), or SIGABRT (ctrl-\ is a common key mapping), SIGTSTP, SIGTTIN, SIGTTOU, SIGHUP, SIGWINCH (and maybe a couple others) are all related to different events on the controlling TTY. There are other considerations beside just signals, as well...